# execute a vbscript from an adobe air app

Tags: air

Is it possible to run a vbscript file from an air app?

I haven't found any examples of this and am unsure if it's possible.

I have a vbscript that automates some printing from word, and wanted to make a front end for this is adobe air.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try to achieve your goal using [Native Process](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html)

Follow some example running a .exe file

```
 var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
 var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("test.exe"); 
 nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file; 
 var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); 
 processArgs.push("hello"); 
 nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs; 
 process = new NativeProcess(); 
 process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 
 process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo); 

 public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
 { 
     var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput; 
     var data:String = stdOut.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable); 
     trace("Got: ", data); 
 }
```